# Open Human Computer Interaction datasets?

Tags: data-request, computing

I am looking for open datasets containing logs of any Human-Computer Interaction (HCI) system. I am interested in analyzing sequences of different aspects of the system, such as:

- User Interaction and commands sequences
- System sequences (events and system state)

Any application domain is valid.